# How to pass variables to javascript in Cakephp 2.3?

Tags: javascript, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to pass a variable array to Javascript in CakePHP 2.3, but can't get it to work. I hope someone has a good solution to this.

I have successfully passed the array to my view by placing the following in the controller:

```
$this->set(compact('myArray'));
```

And tried this in my view to pass the variable through to myJs.js.

```
$this->Js->set('myArray');
$this->Html->script('myJs');
```

Why can't I access the myArray in myJs.js?

Answer (score 4):

**Passing a varible to javascript by using the methods of Js helper**

Just set the variable you want to set using `set` method of `js helper`.

```
$this->Js->set('myArray', $myArray);
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(array('onDomReady' => false));
```

and you can access the `$myArray` variable as `window.app.myArray` your javascript.

Comment: let me know if you've any query or concern @Hans .

Comment: This way I'm getting an error "window.app is undefined". Any ideas?

Comment: check in your view-source whether this variable is set or not

Comment: It would be better to specify `onDomReady` to `false` to prevent the error "window.app" is undefined. Also, looks like `inline` is not necessary as well. So my version is: `echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(array('onDomReady' => false));`

Comment: I just set `inline` to false to show the script at the top of page. I've edited answer for setting `onDomReady` to `false` Thanks for the info. @VCD

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $this->Html->scriptBlock(
    "var myArray = '" . json_encode($myArray) . "'",
    array('inline' => true)
    );
echo $this->Html->script('myJs');
```